# Where can you host a custom Linux Distribution?

Tags: linux, gentoo

I've recently been creating a custom Linux distribution based on Gentoo that includes a custom installer, artwork, development tools, and desktop environment.

I have an ISO image and a local mirror for packages, however I am currently running a mirror privately on a home network with a residential Internet connection.

I was wondering what the next step is to make my distribution public? Where can I host my distribution ISO files, as well as my source code and update files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give [Tuxfamily](http://tuxfamily.org/en/about) a look.

#### About TuxFamily.org

> TuxFamily is a non-profit organization. It provides free services for
>   projects and contents dealing with the free software philosophy (free
>   as in free speech, not as in free beer). We accept any project
>   released under a free license (GPL, BSD, CC-BY-SA, Art Libre...).
>
> Born in 1999 (oh! already?), TuxFamily tries to provide a good and
>   reliable service to promote free projects, making them visible to the
>   users. The hosting is free and we don't add banners or pop-ups to the
>   hosted websites. You don't even have to advertise for TuxFamily! You
>   can also use your own domain name if you have one.
>
> TuxFamily hosting facilities are running on VHFFS, which is a
>   subproject of TuxFamily that makes it possible to manage a massive
>   virtual hosting platform.

#### Services for hosted people

These are the services you can get with TuxFamily. Only one requirement: be a free (as in free speech) project.

- Web hosting (PHP5 is supported)
- MySQL and PostgreSQL databases
- CVS repositories
- Subversion repositories
- GIT repositories
- Mailing-lists
- Manage domain names (DNS hosting) - registration fees are still at your charge
- POP accounts and mail redirects for your domain
- Download area of 1 GB, can be increased if you need more space
- 100 MB quota for all groups, not including the download area, can be increased  if you need more space
- Handling of your data through FTP, FTPS (FTP over SSL), SSH and SFTP

Also found this lxer article: [Best free or low cost places to host a Linux distro repository](http://lxer.com/module/forums/t/32778/).